# How to get data from database and put it into a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on "Time Table Scedualing using genetic algorithm project"
using C# and Sql server..

I divided the Project to 3 Layers (Data Access Layer , business Layer , And interfaces)

Data access layer contains:

(constructor initialize the connection object, Method to open the connection,Method to open the connection ,Method to read data from database, Method to insert , update ,delete data from database)

for example:

//Method to insert , update ,delete data from database

```
 public void ExecuteCommand(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
            if (param != null)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Business Layer Contains class for each form

for example: ADD_PROF.class for "Add Professor Form"

....................

Now to get all data about professors from database,I create (GET_ALL_PROF) procedure and write this code into ADD_PROF Class

```
public DataTable GET_ALL_PROF()  //copied and pasted down for verfing
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Dt = DAL.SelectData("GET_ALL_PROF", null);
            DAL.Close();
            return Dt;

        }
```

My Problem is ... I don't know how to get (Professors ID) from professor table in database and put it into a variable to pass it in genetic algorithm code IN C#?

the procedure in sql is

```
Create proc [dbo].[get_id_PROF] 
as
select ID_PROF from [dbo].[PROFESSOR]
```

Comment: Use SqlDataReader...

Comment: You should look into repositories. It's more modern, flexible and maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `SqlDataReader` for reading the data from your database and simply use it to store data from your database in your variables.

```
int professorId;
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = "select ID_ST from [dbo].[PROFESSOR];";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Call Read before accessing data. 
            if (reader.HasRows())
            { 
                reader.Read(); 
                professorId = reader.GetInt32(0);

                // Call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could try this to use a Stored Procedure:

```
int professorId;
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    sqlConnection1.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
        reader.Read(); 
        professorId = reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
```

- [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Helper Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx)
- [Helper Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19010/Executing-Stored-Procedure-with-Data-Reader)

Comment: Entity Framework is the successor to SqlDataReader. It will do a lot of work for you so you can focus on things that matter instead of sql connections.